# Virtutalenv Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1

Tags: python, pip, setuptools

I've been trying to follow this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x9lKLGTfQFU
and I've come to a problem running the line pip install -r requirements.txt within the virtual environment, this is what happens:

```
(venv) C:\Users\George\Desktop\Kodi> pip install -r requirements.txt
Collecting gunicorn (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/8c/da/b8dd8deb741bff556db53902d4706774c8e1e67265f69528c14c003644e6/gunicorn-19.9.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting pytz (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/30/4e/27c34b62430286c6d59177a0842ed90dc789ce5d1ed740887653b898779a/pytz-2018.5-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting flask-ask>=0.9.8 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/6a/f5/d4709ae94584a0b1541e9b52b2d25a8a1bdb6e2da9d6870f23fdd0523a30/Flask-Ask-0.9.8.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "c:\users\george\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-b3jnkl\flask-ask\setup.py", line 8, in <module>
        from pip.req import parse_requirements
    ImportError: No module named req

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\george\appdata\local\temp\pip-install-b3jnkl\flask-ask\
```

I've looked online, upgraded setuptools and ez install but to no avail

Comment: python version?

Comment: version 2.7.15 as recommended in the guide

Comment: What's pip version..I think you may need to upgrade or downgrade it based on the issue

Comment: according to pip --version, I'm on 10.0.1

Comment: Downgrade `pip` in your venv temporarily: `pip install --upgrade "pip<10" `, then rerun the `pip install -r requirements.txt`. After the installation succeeds, you can roll back to 10.0 if you want: `pip install --upgrade pip`.

Comment: seems to have worked, downgraded to 9.0.3. Thank you guys

Comment: worked for me @hoefling